# Require a file to be checked in / merged in to two places in TFS 2010

Tags: tfs

We have our development branch that has multiple revisions of our code. So it looks like:

> Development
>
> ```
>       R1.0
>       R2.0
>       R3.0
>       Rx
> ```

We are working on multiple releases simultaneously.  So, team A will work on R2.0 while team B will work on R3.0.  While team A is making changes in R2.0, we need to make sure these changes are reflected in R3.0.  Is there a way to require a developer to check in a file to R3.0 if he/she is attempting to check a file in to R2.0?

**Edit 8/1/2013**

After reading several articles on branching and merging strategies, I have an idea of how we should approach the issue.  I just want to run it by you and ask if I'm headed in the right direction.  So, instead of having the development branch and copies of releases, we should have a main (development) branch, and then branch off of it each release.  Then, as frequently as defined in our branching and merging strategy, merge the changes in our R1.0 and R2.0 branches back to the main. And when we want to work on R3.0, we do a fresh merge of everything R1.0 and R2.0 to MAIN, and then create a new branch from MAIN.  Then, say we need a hotfix to R1.0, we create an R1.1 from R1.0 and merge it back up to R1.0 then to MAIN, then from MAIN to R2.0 and R3.0.  As we work on new releases simultaneously, we keep MAIN only as current as our next release.  So if R1.0 has been released already, then MAIN should be kept up to date with R2.0 branch since it will be the next release.  Please correct me if I’m wrong and point me in the right direction.  I am new to branching and merging.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I like your idea and I think it will definitely handle your problem. We are doing something similar except that we have a merge branch(Intermediate branch) in between Main and the Releases.

Main -> Intermediate -> R1

Main -> Intermediate -> R2

Main -> Intermediate -> R3

The advantage of this option is that:

1. You dont have to bring in all the changes to Main (trunk) and Main will stay clear and will act as your GOLDEN production like code.
2. Adds another layer of protection to your golden code. Let's say, the R3 branch was just created from Intermediate, but at that point R2 decided to scrap its release. In this case, if you go with the intermediate branch (which has R1 + R2 at this point) then you can just delete the intermediate branch and branch off from Main( which has only R1) to create a new Intermediate (instead of rolling backing the changes with your approach). Then start off with a new R3.

Just my$0.02

Comment: When do we merge intermediate back to main in this case?

Comment: What happens in our case is that, when R1 development happens R1 changes would be in R1 and Intermediate, all the other branches would take R1 changes from Intermediate. When R1 is ready to be release we merge R1 -> Intermediate -> Main -> R1_Prod

From this point the R2 changes would be in R2 and Intermediate.

Answer (score 2):

You should be using branches to manage the changes between verisons, not having different version of the same code in the same branch.

i.e. R2.0 and R3.0 are both child branches of your main (or trunk) branch. You can then merge changes from R2.0 to Main to R3.0

Read the [ALM Rangers](http://vsarbranchingguide.codeplex.com/) guidance for more information on Branching Strategies